# Combine similar nested dict's values into a new nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key-value

An example of a nested dict that I have to work with looks like this:

```
d1 = {'Breda': {'Fuery': {'anger': 1},
                       'Havoc': {'anticipation': 1, 'surprise': 1},
                       'Hawkeye': {'anticipation': 2}},
             'Fuery': {'Breda': {'anticipation': 2, 'surprise': 1},
                       'Mustang': {'fear': 4}},
             'Havoc': {'Breda': {'joy': 1},
                       'Gloria': {'joy': 1},
                       'Hawkeye': {'anticipation': 4, 'joy': 1, 'surprise': 1},
                       'Mustang': {'surprise': 1}},
             'Hawkeye': {'Hawkeye': {'joy': 2, 'trust': 1},
                         'Mustang': {'anger': 1,
                                     'joy': 6,
                                     'surprise': 4,
                                     'trust': 1}},
             'Mustang': {'Everyone': {'anger': 2},
                         'Fuery': {'anger': 3, 'surprise': 1},
                         'Hawkeye': {'anger': 1,
                                     'joy': 6,
                                     'surprise': 1,
                                     'trust': 1},
                         'Mustang': {'joy': 2, 'trust': 1},
                         'the team': {'anger': 1}}}
```

I am trying to create a new nested dict `d2` from it, having the new keys being the keys of the outermost dict of `d1`, and then the values of each of those keys to be the combination of the values of all the inner `d1`'s keys.

So, if `'anticipation'` for example is showing in more than one key, the values of `'anticipation'` should be added together.

**Desired output** would look like this:

```
d2 = {'Breda': {'anger': 1, 'anticipation': 3, 'surprise': 1},
      'Fuery': {'anticipation': 2, 'surprise': 1, 'fear': 4},
      'Havoc': {'joy': 3, 'anticipation': 4, 'surprise': 2},
      'Hawkeye': {'joy': 8, 'trust': 2, 'anger': 1, 'surprise': 4}
      'Mustang': {'anger': 6, 'surprise': 2, 'joy': 8, 'trust': 2}}
```

So far, I have this code that somehow does not go through all the keys of the inner dict and just outputs the values of the last one:

```
from pprint import pprint

      # see d1 above

d2 = dict()

for key, value in d1.items():

    for k, v in value.items():
        d2[key] = v

pprint(d2)
```

**Current output:**

```
{'Breda': {'anticipation': 2},
 'Fuery': {'fear': 4},
 'Havoc': {'surprise': 1},
 'Hawkeye': {'anger': 1, 'joy': 6, 'surprise': 4, 'trust': 1},
 'Mustang': {'anger': 1}}
```

How do I iterate through **all** the keys of the inner dict and then compare values to add them together?

I hope that my question is clear.

Any kind of hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) on the values of the inner dictionaries:

```
from collections import Counter

d1 = {'Breda': {'Fuery': {'anger': 1},
                'Havoc': {'anticipation': 1, 'surprise': 1},
                'Hawkeye': {'anticipation': 2}},
      'Fuery': {'Breda': {'anticipation': 2, 'surprise': 1},
                'Mustang': {'fear': 4}},
      'Havoc': {'Breda': {'joy': 1},
                'Gloria': {'joy': 1},
                'Hawkeye': {'anticipation': 4, 'joy': 1, 'surprise': 1},
                'Mustang': {'surprise': 1}},
      'Hawkeye': {'Hawkeye': {'joy': 2, 'trust': 1},
                  'Mustang': {'anger': 1,
                              'joy': 6,
                              'surprise': 4,
                              'trust': 1}},
      'Mustang': {'Everyone': {'anger': 2},
                  'Fuery': {'anger': 3, 'surprise': 1},
                  'Hawkeye': {'anger': 1,
                              'joy': 6,
                              'surprise': 1,
                              'trust': 1},
                  'Mustang': {'joy': 2, 'trust': 1},
                  'the team': {'anger': 1}}}

result = {key: dict(sum(map(Counter, inner.values()), Counter())) for key, inner in d1.items()}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Havoc': {'joy': 3, 'surprise': 2, 'anticipation': 4}, 'Mustang': {'joy': 8, 'trust': 2, 'anger': 7, 'surprise': 2}, 'Hawkeye': {'joy': 8, 'surprise': 4, 'anger': 1, 'trust': 2}, 'Breda': {'surprise': 1, 'anger': 1, 'anticipation': 3}, 'Fuery': {'fear': 4, 'surprise': 1, 'anticipation': 2}}
```

The statement `sum(map(Counter, inner.values()), Counter())` transforms each inner dictionary into a Counter and then combine them together using [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). This can be done because Counter implements addition, for instance:

```
Counter({'anticipation': 2}) + Counter({'anticipation': 1, 'surprise': 1})
```

returns:

```
Counter({'anticipation': 3, 'surprise': 1})
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the total for each key, just add these lines:

```
total = { key : sum(inner.values()) for key, inner in result.items() }
print(total)
```

**Output**

```
{'Hawkeye': 15, 'Mustang': 19, 'Fuery': 7, 'Havoc': 9, 'Breda': 5}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! :) - If I'm not being too demanding: is there a possibility to output the sum of all the integers for each individual key? e.g. `Havoc: 9`, `Mustang: 19`

Comment: @Waldkamel Updated the answer!